# Why does the validation email returns an error?

Tags: php, database, authentication

I am developing a Register/Login system with validation. Registering system is working well. For example, when I register the same email twice, the following message appears:

> Email already registered!

However, when I log-in with the same e-mail and password, an error occurs. The following message appears as a validation error:

> Email not registered!

Even if the email is registered in DB.

Code for e-mail validation:

```
<?php

public function validateEmail($par)
{
    if (filter_var($par, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->setErro("Invalid Email!");
        return false;
    }
}

public function validateIssetEmail($email, $action = null)
{
    $b = $this->cadastro->getIssetEmail($email);

    if ($action == null) {
        if ($b > 0) {
            $this->setErro("Email already registered!");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        if ($b > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->setErro("Email not registered!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for login controller:

```
<?php

$validate = new Classes\ClassValidate();
$validate->validateFields($_POST);
$validate->validateEmail($email);
$validate->validateIssetEmail($email,"login");
$validate->validateStrongSenha($senha);
$validate->validateSenha($email,$senha);
var_dump($validate->getErro());
```

Code for class login:

```
<?php

namespace Models;

class ClassLogin extends ClassCrud
{

    # Returns user data
    public function getDataUser($email)
    {
        $b = $this->selectDB(
            "*",
            "users",
            "where email=?",
            array(
                $email
            )
        );
        $f = $b->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $r = $b->rowCount();
        return $arrData = [
            "data" => $f,
            "rows" => $r
        ];
    }
}
```

My `getIssetEmail` method exists on Register code only.

```
# Check directly at the bank if the email is registered     
public function getIssetEmail($email)
{         
    $b = $this->selectDB(             
        "*",             
        "users",             
        "where email=?",             
        [                 
            $email             
        ]        
    );         
    return $r = $b->rowCount(); // returns the amount of rows in the search     
}
```

And ClassPassword

```
<?php

namespace Classes;

use Models\ClassLogin;

class ClassPassword
{

    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new ClassLogin();
    }


    # Create password's hash to save in DB
    public function passwordHash($senha)
    {
        return password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }


    # Verify if password's hash is correct
    public function verifyHash($email, $senha)
    {
        $hashDb = $this->db->getDataUser($email);
        return password_verify($senha, $hashDb["data"]["senha"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This statement looks weird: `return $r = $b->rowCount()`

Comment: Indeed. But it works perfectly on registering an user. :/

Comment: Right before this line `$this->setErro("Email not registered!");` print out the value of `$b` to see what is in there.

Comment: It prints 0. I think it isnt's "searching" for data (email)

Comment: Is it `0` or `"0"`? In the `validateIssetEmail` method, go condition-by-condition and dump variables out to see the flow.

Comment: "0" means 0 haha, sorry

Comment: could you exemplify?

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer but hopefully it will help in debugging.*

First, I'm going to change your code. This is 100% a style choice but I personally think it is easier to follow. If you have an `if` statement that always `returns`, you don't technically need an `else`. Once again, this is a style choice and you don't have to follow it.

Second, if you can, try adding logging into your workflow, it will save you so much time debugging. It isn't always an option, especially for legacy code bases, but it is awesome when you can inspect complex code. In this example, I"m just making a couple of helper methods that dump stuff but normally I'd use something like Monolog to write to a stream that I can `tail`, and I can easily turn it off in production. When logging, sometimes it helps to avoid identical messages so that you can easily find the exact line number you are on, too.

So with those changes, try running this code inside of your class:

```php
    private function logMessage($message)
    {
        echo $message . PHP_EOL;
    }

    private function logVariable($variable)
    {
        var_dump($variable);
    }

    public function validateIssetEmail($email, $action = null)
    {
        $this->logVariable($email);
        $this->logVariable($action);

        $b = $this->cadastro->getIssetEmail($email);

        $this->logVariable($b);

        if ($action === null) {
            $this->logMessage('Action was null');
            if ($b > 0) {
                $this->logMessage('B is greater than zero');
                $this->setErro("Email already registered!");
                return false;
            }

            $this->logMessage('B was not greater than zero');

            return true;
        }

        $this->logMessage('Action was not null');
        if ($b > 0) {
            $this->logMessage('B is greater than zero');
            return true;
        }

        $this->logMessage('B was not greater than zero');
        $this->setErro("Email not registered!");
        return false;
    }
```

This should log in human-readable form every step. You should be able to walk through this and identify where your bug is. For instance, in the comments above you said that a variable was `0` in a block that was guarded by a check that guarantees that that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Can I put exactly this form?

Comment: `NULL string(5) "login" int(0) Action was not null B was not greater than zero` this returned

Comment: If the first thing is `NULL`, that means `$email` is empty

Comment: So, I understood that the code "ignored" `if ($action == null)` once Action was not null, but B was not greater than zero, even with an email...

Comment: Why `$email` is empty?

Comment: We can't answer that question for you, we can only tell you that by the time it reaches this method it is empty. The next step for you is to go the line of code that calls this method and right before `var_dump` that variable. Then keep walking up until you see where the problem is.

Comment: I saw there were more errors when it try to validate. It sounds like no validation is working as they should. Password, Email, Both confirmation.... nothing

Comment: So at this point, it really sounds like you need to work on what comes before the class-related stuff, right? Just getting the basic variables setup, handling `$_POST`, etc.? There isn't anything else in this thread that we can help you with, is there?

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong part i guess you assigned login as action so you can call cadastro class inside of the function

```
$cadastro = new Cadastro();
$b = $cadastro->getIssetEmail($email);


if ($action == null) {
        if ($b > 0) {
            $this->setErro("Email already registered!");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        if ($b > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->setErro("Email not registered!");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, I think u forgot one line which contains `$b = $this->cadastro->getIssetEmail($email);`. If I change  and put $r intead $b, I must define $r before

Comment: what is cadastro actually ? it might be returning a value that you can't compare with 0

Comment: I forgot to translate... it means "register"... it comes from ClassCadastro (ClassRegister), which is independent from Login system

Comment: Looks like the validations aren't working correctly on Login

Comment: You opened a <?php before these functions but there is no class so in that case maybe $this->cadastro not returning anything, updated my answer accordingly :)